# Port mapping in Docker

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, pyramid, dockerfile

I created a docker for a sample python pyramid app. My dockerfile is this:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev curl && \
    pip install --upgrade pip setuptools

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

EXPOSE 6543

RUN pip install -e .

ENTRYPOINT [ "pserve" ]

CMD [ "development.ini" ]
```

My build command is this:

```
docker build -t pyramid_app:latest .
```

My run command is this:

```
docker run -d -p 6543:6543 pyramid_app
```

When i try to access http://localhost:6543 I get an error

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_SOCKET_NOT_CONNECTED
```

When I curl inside the machine it works fine.

It would be great if someone could help me figure out why my port mapping isn't working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in your pserve config, change

```
[server:main]
listen = 127.0.0.1:6543
```

to

```
[server:main]
listen = *:6543
```

otherwise the web server will only accept connections from the docker container itself

Comment: awesome. that worked. I made a minor change. put host: 0.0.0.0. But this answer is definitely correct. thanks a lot